# Can i test cypress to capture signature from network tools

Tags: cypress, developer-tools

When i click on some url it triggers one signature url under Developer tools->network tools.
Can i use cypress to test anything which is triggered in Developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at [Intercept command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept)? You can grab just about any network request with it.

Most basic form:

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/users*',
  hostname: 'localhost',
}).as('usersRequest')

cy.wait('@usersRequest')
  .then(interception => {
    // interception has similar data to Chrome devtools
  })
```

Comment: In my network tools  i have a ping in the form of url that is of plain/text.
How i can intercept that request

Comment: You should be able to just put that url in the intercept. Can you show a screen-shot in the question?